# Generate integers with even hamming weight (popcount) c++

Tags: c++, subset, gray-code, hammingweight

I want to effectively (by using bit hacks) generate all integers up a given number, k, such that they have an even hamming weight without explicitly calculating their hamming weights. It is not important to me whether that is done in ascending or descending order.

A bonus (related task) would be if I could generate all integers with even hamming weight which are subsets (in the Gray code sense) of k.

Example:
input-> k=14 (binary 1110)

output all-> 3 (0011), 5(0101), 6 (0110), 9 (1001), 10 (1010), 12 (1100)

output subsets-> 6 (0110), 10 (1010), 12 (1100)

Example code using popcount:

```
for (unsigned int sub=1; sub<k; sub++){
  if (__builtin_popcount(sub) % 2 == 0){
    cout << sub << endl;
  }
}
```

Example code using popcount for subsets:

```
for (unsigned int sub=((k-1)&k); sub!=0; sub=((sub-1)&k)){
  if (__builtin_popcount(sub) % 2 == 0){
    cout << sub << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where were you stuck?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer: I know how to simply generate a subset of an integer (for the second part): `for (unsigned int sub = k; sub != 0; sub = (( sub - 1 ) & k ))`, but without explicitly using the popcount function I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Also what is it with everyone down-voting without even bothering to comment.

Comment: The first comment explains the reason for the down votes.

Comment: @FedorŠimkovic Unfortunately this forum is very toxic to people who do not know what they are doing. Its kind of ironic. You may get more success with an answer if you fleshed out your question with some example code you have tried, perhaps show the long hand code you wish to avoid. It reads like you have written out your home work and not googled anything. I think some examples of what you actually want would help. Example input and output. I don't know the subject but it reads like you want the answer without doing a calculation.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw, I have done that with previous posts and still got down-voted... I find flashing the long code not particularly helpful in this particular example, but fair enough. I'll edit the post with more details.

Comment: Not sure of your motivation. What is the upper limit of k. One solution, for example, is calculate offline and create a table. Read table until entry is greater than k. Also builtin can be much faster than a soft alternative. Depending on the platform. So may be faster than optimised soft alternative. (I think you can just test the bottom bit for even without the % operator.)

Comment: In principle I want to repeatedly do this for all k's from 1 up to 2^12 (there's some simple multiplication+addition happening inside the loop instead of cout), so speed is my motivation.

Answer (score 1):

We can build a tree with numbers in nodes, each node has two childs, one with flipped bit number x and the other with not flipped bit number x. We need to exclude all the childs with value greater then initial value. We can store the popcount in a variable and decrement and increment each time we flip a bit depending on the flipped bit value, thus avoiding calculating popcount each time the variable is changed.
I don't know if this method is faster or not. I guess it may be faster, but the overhead for recursive function may be too big. 
That was fun:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cassert>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>

namespace gen {

bool isEven(unsigned int x) {
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

// find last set bit, just like ffs, but backwards
unsigned int fls(unsigned int x)
{
    assert(x >= 1);
    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
#ifdef __GNUC__
    const unsigned int clz = __builtin_clz(x);
#else
    #error find clz function in C++
#endif
    assert(clz >= 1 && (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT) >= clz + 1);
    return (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT) - clz - 1;
}

unsigned int popcount(unsigned int x) {
#ifdef __GNUC__
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
#else
    return std::bitset<sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT>(x).count();
#endif
}

/**
 * Generates all integers up a given number k with even hamming weight
 * @param out - output vector with push_backed results
 * @param greycodesubset - set to true, if only interested in grey subset integers only
 * @param startk - starting k value
 * @param k - the current number value
 * @param pos - one plus the position of the bit in number k that we will change in this run
 * @param popcount - Hamming weight of number k up to position pos
 * @param changes - the number of bits changed in number k since startk. Used only if greycodesubset = true
 */
void loop(std::vector<unsigned int>& out, const bool& greycodesubset, 
    const unsigned int& startk,
    unsigned int k, unsigned int pos, unsigned int popcount,
    unsigned int changes)
{
    // k > startk may happen for example for 0b10, if we flip last byte, then k = 0b11
    if (startk < k) {
        return;
    }
    // end of recusive function
    if (pos == 0) {
        if (isEven(popcount) && k != 0) {
            out.push_back(k);
        }
        return;
    }
    // decrement pos
    --pos;

    const int mask = 1 << pos;
    const bool is_pos_bit_set = k & mask;

    // call without changes
    loop(out, greycodesubset, startk, 
        k, pos, popcount + (is_pos_bit_set ? +1 : 0), changes);
    // when finding grey code subset only we can change maximum 1 byte
    if (greycodesubset) {
        if (changes >= 1) {
            return;
        }
        ++changes;
    }
    // call with toggled bit number pos
    loop(out, greycodesubset, startk, 
        k ^ mask, pos, popcount + (!is_pos_bit_set ? +1 : 0), changes);
}

std::vector<unsigned int> run(const unsigned int& k, const bool& greycodesubsetonly)
{
    assert(k > 0);
    std::vector<unsigned int> out;
    if (k < 2) return out;

    loop(out, greycodesubsetonly, k, k, fls(k) + 1, 0, 0);

    return out;
}

} // namespace gen

int main()
{
    const unsigned int k = 14;
    const int bits_in_k = 4;

    std::vector<unsigned int> out = gen::run(k, false);
    std::vector<unsigned int> out_subset = gen::run(k, true);

    std::cout << "input-> k=" << k << "(" << std::bitset<bits_in_k>(k).to_string() << ") " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "output all-> ";
    std::for_each(out.begin(), out.end(), [](int v) {
        std::cout << v << "(" << std::bitset<bits_in_k>(v).to_string() << ") ";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "output subsets-> ";
    std::for_each(out_subset.begin(), out_subset.end(), [](int v) {
        std::cout << v << "(" << std::bitset<bits_in_k>(v).to_string() << ") ";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
input-> k=14(1110)                                                                                                           
output all-> 12(1100) 10(1010) 9(1001) 6(0110) 5(0101) 3(0011)                                                               
output subsets-> 12(1100) 10(1010) 6(0110)
```